# How can I make transform:translate work to make an element centered on screen?

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find a solution for this simple problem, I changed the display to flex and block, that didn't work either. It works on parent element. But I guess there is something I can't see on this code.

```
.planets {
  display: flex;

  height: 100vh;
}
.pluton-orbit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70rem;
  height: 70rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.219);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
  z-index: 4;
  animation: Rotation 5s linear infinite;
}
```

the transform here, doesn't work. I know how to center, my question is why doesn't the transform property work. this is react with Sass by the way. Everything else works in the code, just the transform. here is the component.

```
import React from "react";

const Planets: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="planets">
      <div className="pluton-orbit">
        <div className="pluton"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="neptun-orbit">
        <div className="neptun"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Planets;
```

Comment: CSS alone barely tells us anything. When you ask these types of questions, please always provide a _proper_ [mre] of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

The `top: 50%; left: 50%;` positions the element's top/left corner at the center of the closest positioned ancestor. Then, the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` moves the element up and to the left by 50% of the element's size.

If you apply animation that alters the `transform` property, make sure you merge it with the initial `transform` value, since it will override the entire `transform` rule for that element. For example:

```css
.element {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%)}
  to {transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-50%, -50%)}
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx0cqLut/)

Comment: so transform here doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @İlker I added a fiddle

Comment: I edited the question, my problem is everything works but transform.

Comment: @İlker I see that you are using `rem` units for the `width/height`. This unit is based on the `font-size` and may cause you some issues. Try using pixels instead.

Comment: Yes but I fixed the font-size to 62.5% in html so I know exactly the pixel values. I just comment out the animation and it worked. The animation Rotation and transform doesn't work together for some reason.

Comment: @İlker Right, if your animation has something like `transform: rotate(...)` you will need to change it to `transform: rotate(...) translate(-50%, -50%)` because it overrides the entire `transform` rule for that element.

Comment: yes okay, thank you. I figured it out, it's how you said :)

Answer (score -1):

give position absolute to element and

```
top:50%;

left:50%;

transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```